# SOLVED:gbak restoring DB raises violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint

Tags: firebird

I'm copying database from production to test env.
Both of servers are Firebird x64 v3.0.4.

I caught following error messages and stopped gbak -R.

> gbak: ERROR:violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint "RDB$INDEX_12" on table "RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS"
>
> gbak: ERROR:    Problematic key value is ("RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME" = 'RDB$INDEX_0')

How to find target constraints and indexes?

Comment: Connect to source database (i.e. database from which backup was made) and look at system tables to determine what RDB$INDEX_0 stands for.

Comment: RDB$INDEX_0 is unique index for RDB$RELATIONS.

Answer (score 0):

It is my mistake.

I ran gbak for firebird 3.0 database from firebird 2.5 client.
I could import backup files successfully.

Thanks.

Comment: you did run it when you was CREATING the backup or when you was RESTORING from the backup? Also, did you use -se switch ?

Comment: I ran gbak -B from fb 2.5 client environment and ran gbak -C/-R on FB 3.0 server. Without -T option at backup. Without -se but I specified target server as localhost:/xxx.

Comment: `Without -se but I specified` - those are very different things, so there is no "BUT" at all. Without -se option it is your local program, gbak.exe, which makes the backup process. With -se option it would be the remote server which proceeds with the backup. When your remote server and your local program are of different version, the presence/absence of the option decides which version of backup engine would be actually invoked.

Comment: I didn't understand about -se. Thank you.